# VBA Email Signature Code Proof

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm fairly new to VBA and I'm having trouble writing a macro that creates an email with my signature already attached. Can someone let me know what exactly is wrong with my code and how I can fix it?

```
Sub SendFIleAsAttachment()

    Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OLMail As Object
    signature As String

    Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OLMail = OLApp.CreateItem(0)
    OLApp.Session.Logon

    With OLMail
    .Display
    End With
        signature = OMail.Body
    With OMail
    .To = "email"
    .CC = "email"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "New Copy Proofing Request"
    .Body = "body text. Thanks!" & vbNewLine & signature
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    End With
    Set OLMail = Nothing
    Set OLApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think Microsoft have done a lot over the years to make this difficult. Using the VBE inspector to examine OLMail (once the typo and the declaration are fixed as @Vityata suggests) I see that the `.Body` (even though the mail contains a signature) is `<>` -  which is null I guess as it errors when attempting to load it to a string.

Comment: This might be some kind of permission issue though, I'm on a corporate set-up. You may get different results!

Comment: @CLR - strange, what is `<>`? My code below works quite ok actually.

Comment: @Vityata I think it's the VBE's attempt at representing a null object (`Nothing`). Or a null of some kind. I think I read somewhere that there's a setting somewhere in GP or similar can prevent certain things being 'visible' to VBA and perhaps this is one. I had to get around it once by reading the .rtf file from %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures but there's no way to detect which is the default signature if more than one exists.

Comment: @CLR - I see, thanks for sharing the info. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are misspelling `OLMail` and `OMail`  and you are missing the word `Dim` once in your code. To fix this kind of grammer mistakes, follow the good practice inserting `Option Explicit` on the top of your Module/Worksheet - [What do Option Strict and Option Explicit do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do)

```
Sub SendFIleAsAttachment()

    Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OLMail As Object
    Dim signature As String

    Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OLMail = OLApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OLMail
        .Display
    End With
    signature = OLMail.Body
    With OLMail
        .To = "email"
        .CC = "email"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "New Copy Proofing Request"
        .Body = "body text. Thanks!" & vbNewLine & signature
    End With

End Sub
```